# How to get WP marketplace like listbox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I'de like to make a listbox which loads data by a custom number of rows. More like the listbox the marketplace has. Any ideas?

edit: I meant the way how that listbox works. It loads the marketplace data by x rows at a time. I'd like it to load datarows by a number of x so the app don't have to load all the data at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ExtendedListBox` control from this library: http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com

```
public MyPage()
{
    list.ScrolledToEnd += OnScrolledToEnd;
}

public void OnScrolledToEnd(object sender, ScrolledToEndEventArgs args)
{
    list.TriggerScrolledToEndEvents = false; 
    // TODO load more data async. => call OnDataLoaded on loaded
}

public void OnDataLoaded()
{
    // TODO add new items to list
    list.TriggerScrolledToEndEvents = true; 
}
```

If you encounter problems using this class please inform me here.

More information: http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ExtendedListBox

Answer (score 1):

Have a list box with wrap panel instead of stack panel Or add grid inside the listboxe and make the images to add in the grid in a custom row and column

Add a wrap panel it arrange the images in rows then add backround worker class like this. It will add im ages onebyone in rows.

var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

```
worker.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)

{

    // Loop through all the items

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count - 1; i++)

    {

        // Create a slight delay and add each item to the Items collection

        Thread.Sleep(200);

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
         () =>

            {

                Items.Add(items[i]);

            });

    }

};
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)

{

};

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

}

In your list in a row if you have 4 images. try to have like in background worker class.

Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
             () =>

```
            {

              Add first 4 items in list box then start the loop at index 5

            });
```

Comment: Thank I did that already. I have images and everything. I need to make it load data by a number of x rows.

Answer (score 1):

See if `VirtualizingStackPanel` meets your requirement?

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441510/listbox-data-virtualization-is-not-taking-effect)

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx)