# How to navigate fast when UI has many elements?

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface, pivot, element

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app. In my main page, there is a pivot which has 6 `PivotItem`. In each of these `PivotItems` are a `ListBox` which has many texts and images.

When I navigate from main page to Page 1, it takes very long time (about 5-8s). The heavier UI on main page, the longer it takes.

I cannot reduce the elements on main page, so what is the advice to go to Page 1 fast ?

Comment: Does this happen when you navigate to a specific 'Page 1', or it happens irrelevant of the page you're navigating to ?

Comment: @AdrianFaciu page1 is just an example. It is slows when the navigate to blank page, either

Comment: Do you have any handlers for events like OnNavigatedFrom, OnNavigatingFrom ? Or maybe some background loading ? The heavier UI should affect loading time of the page itself, not sure why it affects performance when navigating to a different page.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu I think when navigating to page1, the OS must put main page to the BackStack, and perhaps collapse its elements, is this the case ?

Comment: Yes the OS will put the page in the backstack, but i'm not sure if it can affect performance that badly so I was guessing that there could be other causes for the bad performance.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu and when I navigate back to main page, it takes long time to show main page, too :(

Answer (score 1):

Collapse the root element of pivot items that are not currently visible, and make them visible when they are brought into view.  Most likely you are keeping the UI thread arranging and drawing UI elements that are not visible.

This will allow you to monitor memory and graphics performance

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```

[How to interpret FrameRateCounter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssehgal/archive/2012/07/17/windows-phone-emulator-frame-rate-counters.aspx)

Comment: you mean collapse the whole pivot? where should I collapse, in OnNavigatedFrom or Unloaded ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are navigating from a main page to another page that contains a pivot control.  Place a grid as a root element of your pivot items and collapse them.  Set Page 1 visible in OnNavigated to.  That way your page navigation will be faster.  You can selectively set the elements to visible on SelectionChanged or loaded.

Comment: My main page is heavy and contains pivot control. When I navigate from main page to page 1, it seems that the OS must do some work to put main page to backstack, hence slows down the navigation

Comment: I didn't think changing pivot items affected the back stack.  Why do you think it does?

Comment: I don't mean changing pivot items, I mean heavy UI affect navigation. I try using lots of elements of main page, when navigate back to main page from page1, it takes very long time to show main page

Comment: I understand.  Are your listboxes virtualized? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441510/listbox-data-virtualization-is-not-taking-effect

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21493/discussion-between-kindasimple-and-entropy)