# List box with over 100 items crashes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone, listboxitems

I am working on windows phone 8 app.

I have List box with over 200 items to display.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="White" Height="400" Width="400" CornerRadius="30,30,30,30">
                </Border>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="5,20,5,5"
                               Foreground="#000000"
                               Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

But it crashes, i have debugged it till 100 items it works but after that it crashes.

In the `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded` method i have

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
myList.Add(new MyObject("A","A value"));
            myList.Add(new MyObject("B", "B value"));
            myList.Add(new MyObject("C", "C value"));

and so on... 200 items

ListBoxItems.ItemsSource = myList;
}
```

how can i fix this ?

**Update :**

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate">
            <local:CollectionFlowPanel ItemHeight="400" 
                                       ItemWidth="400"
                                       FocusedItemOffset="120" 
                                       UnfocusedItemOffset="20" 
                                       ItemVisibility="5">
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </local:CollectionFlowPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#000000">
        <local:CollectionFlow x:Name="ListBoxItems"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" 
                              ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What is the error the crash shows?

Comment: @NicholasV. some times it shows `Out of Memory error`

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you have VirtualizingStackPanel inside the ItemsPanelTemplate of your list box, [see this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7463524/126995).

Here's the XAML you likely need for your ListBox:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: but how does this affect from app crashing for 200+ items ?

Comment: GUI elements aren't free. They’re backed by the texture memory on the GPU, and are thus quite expensive.
Qualcomm system on a chip inside a windows phone device don’t have a dedicated GPU chip (it’s integrated) neither dedicated video RAM (system RAM is used by both CPU, GPU and DSP).
I suspect with your 200 elements, 400 pixels each, you're running out of the system memory due to the GPU wants to allocate too many textures for your GUI elements.

With VirtualizingStackPanel, only a few visual elements are created, and they’re reused to display different items as you scroll the list.

Comment: ok i didnt know about that, can you please help me where i need to add it in my case ? and also i did one more thing if i set the Border width and height to 200 it displays without any error, but if its 400 it gives me OOM.Why so ? any idea?

Comment: If required i can send you the entire POC that i have it to you ? shall i send you ?

Comment: “where I need to add it in my case” — see the update. "Why so?" — because the amount of RAM is proportional to Width*Height of the texture. When you increase the total area of your elements, you need more memory for the textures.

Comment: it gives me error `Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel.`

Comment: Please see my EDIT as well

Comment: You can't have both your custom local:CollectionFlowPanel and VirtualizingStackPanel as your items panel. To use virtualization, replace your CollectionFlowPanel with system-provided VirtualizingStackPanel.

Comment: @Soonts here Virtualizatoin issue is not from inside of The listbox but outside I have tried your solution by implementing Virtualizating StackPanel the result is the same. I think ListBox is in canvas/stackpanel control and no widht height is defined for listbox that is causing the issue.

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah, please reload the question: the OP has posted the XAML with some custom CollectionFlowPanel that obviously doesn't support virtualization (virtualizing panels are hard to implement correctly, e.g. MS-provided VirtualizingStackPanel is over 2000 lines of C# code).

Answer (score 1):

You need to read following blog from msdn on visualization of the data in list and grid.

**[Using virtualization with a list or grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx)**

Without seeing your whole xaml code I cannot suggest the exact answer but my guess is that you in xaml ListBox is placed inside a canvas/StackPanel or scrollviewer control.

> When the size of the ItemsControl's viewport isn't restricted, the control doesn't perform virtualization. Instead, it creates an item container for each item in its collection. Some common containers that don't restrict the viewport size are Canvas, StackPanel, and ScrollViewer. You can enable virtualization in this situation by setting the size of ItemsControl directly, instead of letting it be sized by its parent container.
>   Here, we set the Height and Width on the GridView. This restricts the size of the viewport, and items outside of the viewport are virtualized.

Below are 2 scenarios one will throw out of memory exception and other will work fine(use your same code behind and test)

**1. ListBox in Canvas**

```
 <Canvas .....
    <ListBox Name="ListBoxItems".....
    </ListBox>
 </Canvas>
```

*Above code will throw out of memory exception as items control's viewport is not defined (**if you still want to use Canvas than define width/height if ListBox in that case the port of Items control is defined and virtulazation will apply**)*

**2. ListBox in Grid**

```
  <Grid .....
    <ListBox Name="ListBoxItems".....
    </ListBox>
 </Grid>
```

The above code will not throw out of memory exception as virtuallization is applied on the listbox.

Hope this will help

Comment: Shall i share my project ? please give me your mail id

Comment: I have sent it to you, can you plese invite me to some chat room so that i can explain you

Comment: please check that , i will wait for your reply

Comment: Did you find any solution for that why its happening ?

Comment: I have checked your code.... you are using custom panel(not the list control which is virtualized by default. Inherit your CollectionFlowPanel class with VirtualizingPanel instead of just pannel to get advantages of virtualization. I have inherited with VirtualizingPanel and loading 5000 records. Now exception is not thorws but I cannot see the items on main view. You can check your code on these lines.

Comment: yes,i have Inherited CollectionFlowPanel class with VirtualizingPanel instead of just pannel , but the items are not showing , any idea why ?

Comment: follow those blog post series for implementing VirtualiingPanel. it will help. 

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/13/531550.aspx

Comment: i am not getting what changes that i need to make , can you point me some things ?

Answer (score -1):

How big is your object ? If your object is too big you might not be able to load them all at once.

Comment: it has 200+ items in it, is it because of the border width and height ? because i decreased it from 400 to 200 it displays but i want it 400

Comment: What I meant is, how much memory an object of type "MyObject" takes ? It is approximately the sum of what your object is made of. For example, if your object contains 4 integers, the amount of memory your object will consume is four times the size of an integer. If your object contains media elements like pictures of videos, it might consume a whole lot of memory and thus you will have this "OutOfMemoryException".

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the for loop?

```
public List<Fellow> fellowList { get; set; }

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{

fellowList = new List<Fellow>();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Fellow fellow = new Fellow();
    fellow.x = "B" + i;
    fellow.value = "B Value" + i;
    fellowList.Add(fellow);
}
this.DataContext = this;

ListBoxItems.ItemsSource = fellowList;    

}

public class Fellow
{
public string x { get; set; }
public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps..change the view model according to your wish